# Single-entry/single-exit rule

Tags: c++, return-value

I have read a rule somewhere to:

> Follow the single-entry/single-exit rule. Never write multiple return statements in the same function.

Is this statement true? If that so, could you please give more detail as to why we should follow this rule?

Comment: "Is this true?" Well you don't *have* to follow it, the language is perfectly happy with multiple `return` statements, and in my opinion it's fine to use them. The problem is when you have a lot of `return`s in complicated nested logic. That can be hard to follow. If your function has a lot of `return`s you probably need to refactor. You may also be interested to know that in Fortran, functions can have multiple entry points as well, and people do use them.

Comment: It's also worth remembering that your functions may exit via an exception as well, complicating things further, and it's often difficult to know where they might come from.

Comment: This sounds like something a C programmer might say. In C++, early exit is a very useful idiom.

Comment: SESE doesn't add much value in garbage-collected languages like C# and Java, but it's good practice for C and C++. Leaks or crashes due to missing or incorrect clean up logic is a very common mistake. Even if you are flawless in ensuring that every exit point in your functions cleans up correctly, maintenance programmers are much more likely to introduce errors when they add additional checking for conditions that weren't initially anticipated but showed up during testing. SESE ensures that there's only one chunk of code per function that handles clean-up, and there's no way to circumvent it.

Comment: I'll just add that I'd call SESE a 'good practice', not a rule. If your function can throw an exception, you need to catch it so that you can clean up before rethrowing it or exiting normally. If you need to rethrow the exception, you may find that having multiple exit points, each with its own copy of the clean up code is the best option.

Comment: There is a question on the topic on SE Software Engineering, with very good answers : [Where did the notion of “one return only” come from?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/118703). (I'll leave that here because I think it could help people looking for stuffs on the subject)

Comment: It is false. the principle of "single entry-single exit subprogram" comes from a time when people tried to foster "structured programming". C++ as a language that is structured. Except for longjmp() all functions have a single exit, regardless of how many return statements are there, because they all will return to the same place (the functions call site).

In the 1960s that was not necessarily true in programs. So the mapping from IEC61508 of the term "single exit" to a "single return" in C++ is wrong!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm personally not opposed to early-exit, but I'll propose a third alternative to SingerOfTheFall for consideration.

Advantages:

- normal code flow (i.e. non-error) flows cleanly through the top of
  the code
- no chance of failing one "something" and passing another
  "something" inadvertently executing a block of code
- you can enforce scope on code blocks; including clean-up on exit of scope for things used in sub-blocks of code

Disadvantage:

- indentations can add up (although this can be mitigated by breaking
  into sub-functions)
- without brace-matching in your editor it can be difficult to match error with failed condition

```
int foo()
{
    int errorCode = 0;
    if(!something) {
        //100 lines of code
        if(!something) {
            //100 lines of code
            if(!something) {
                //100 lines of code
            }
            else {
                errorCode = -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            errorCode = 11;
       }
    }
    else {
        errorCode = 1;
    }
    return errorCode;
}
```

Comment: i know this is quite old, but this is unreadable code. even without it being a multiple "100 lines of code" method. The nesting is a horror.

Answer (score 25):

> Is this true?

That's what the rule says, in places where it's used and enforced. Is it a good rule? I fight against its adoption tooth and nail. I think its a stupid rule. Worse than stupid: It's a harmful rule for C++.

I do agree with the first part of the rule, "single entry". The Fortran `entry` statement causes a lot more problems than it solves. This first part of the rule does not pertain to C or C++ for the simple reason that neither language provides a multiple entry point mechanism. "Single entry" is a no-op in C and C++.

So what about "single exit"? Early return does not necessarily cause problems. Failing to deal with allocated resources prior to returning is what causes problems. The right rule is "clean up your mess", or don't leave dangling resources. Single exit does not solve this problem because it doesn't say a thing about cleaning up your mess.

In C, the single entry / single exit rule typically goes hand in hand with allowing (and even encouraging) the use of `goto` for error handling. I can see the place for `goto` as used for error handling in the Linux kernel code. But not in C++. This is why I wrote that single entry / single exit is harmful in C++. This rule discourages the use of RAII and exception-safe programming and encourages the use of `goto`.

Comment: your answer and SingerOfTheFall's should be combined on a single one to explain why the single exit is quite ridiculous.

Comment: I think the original purpose  of the rule was to avoid 500 line long methods/procedures/functions and keep them short and simple, but it got out of hand: The one method/procedure/function does one thing and one thing only, cleaning up your mess and trying to keep side effects to a minimum is what should be thought instead, if anything. More than 30 lines per method/procedure/function is a code smell. No rule is absolute but simplifying code like this with good naming conventions usually gets you portable and maintainable code and avoids redundancy.

Comment: @NotGaeL - Sorry for the late response; this question keeps coming up. I've seen plenty of SESE functions that are well over 1000 lines long, have a cylcomatic complexity over 100, and are nested 10 levels deep. Those are problems, so attack them directly. Multiple return statements, done correctly, can reduce lines of code, cyclomatic complexity (and more importantly, a vague human concept of complexity), and nesting levels.

Comment: you are probably right. Like I wrote: no rule is absolute. It mostly depends on the context. Since my comment I've seen enough low level embedded device code to understand why a long function would make sense. Still, almost every time compiler optimizations beat anything you can do by putting everything on the same block of code. And still, the number 1 reason for seeing those monstruiosities is, in my experience, lack of coder experience. And almost every time it goes hand by hand with enourmous chunks of copypasted duplicated code all over the place.

Answer (score 12):

No, this is not a rule, and sometimes it is even difficult/impossible to achieve. The code that has one entry and one exit point is easier to understand and debug though. Compare this:

```
int foo()
{
    if(something)
        return 0;
    //100 lines of code
    if(something)
        return 11;
    //100 lines of code
    if(something)
        return -1;
    //100 lines of code
    return 0;
}
```

and this:

```
int foo()
{
    int errorCode = 0;
    if(something)
        errorCode = 1;
    //100 lines of code
    if(something)
        errorCode = 11;
    //100 lines of code
    if(something)
        errorCode = -1;
    //100 lines of code
    return errorCode;
}
```

Now we have just one exit point, and (taking into account the variable name too) it's much easier to understand what the function does. You can also place a breakpoint onto the last return and know that this is the point where function ends, and that you will definitely hit it.

Comment: The example with `errorCode` may not be the best one, since you may want to actually stop execution right where the error occurs, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Actually, your second example might be bugged, if it's supposed to do the same as the first since "return" stops executing the function, whereas you are continuing with the code that follows. In cases like this, I generally check the return value for a special "not set" value that gets set at the beginning.

Comment: @Christian Sieber : the order on the second example should be -1,11,0  instead of 1,11,-1 to match the first one but it doesn't really matter. It's quite clear what it wants to exemplify: One exit is less efficient and harder to read, at least in cases like that.

Comment: The biggest problem with this code, or the code in the accepted answer is a 310 line long function. That's long even by most C standards.

Comment: I think the lost point in here is that the main advantage of single exit is to make properly resource cleanup at one single point in the function. If, for any reason more reasources are needed in a (long) function, it is horrible to keep hunting for exit points to add the proper cleanup of that new resource repeatedly. Failing to do so will result in leakage. Also reminding that duplicated code is another source of bugs and can make a function needlessly longer than it had to be.

Answer (score 6):

This rule may apply in C, but it can be considered obsolete in C++ because of exceptions. As soon as your function throws an exception or calls a function that can throw, you have an additional exit point:

```
int f()
{
  //...
  g(); // g() may throw: you have an exit point here
  //...
  throw exc; // another possible exit point
  //...
  return returnValue; // Nice try, but you have additional exit points
}
```

This in addition to the point made in other answers: this rule intends to make the code easier to follow, but it is easy to find examples where this is not true. Much better:

```
if (condition)
  return a;
if (condition2)
  return b;
if (condition3)
  return c;

// Insert all your code for the general case
```

than:

```
int returnValue;    
if (!condition) {
  if (!condition2) {
    if (!condition3) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
    else {
      returnValue = c;
    }
    returnValue = b;  // Where am I now?
  }
  returnValue = a;
}
return returnValue;
```

And then you also have the case when you decide the return value in a `switch`:

```
switch (a)
{
  case 1: return 10;
  case 2: return 20;
  case 3: return 40;
  default: return 50;
}
```

rather than:

```
int returnValue;
switch (a)
{
  case 1: returnValue = 10; break;
  case 2: returnValue = 20; break;
  case 3: returnValue = 40; break;
  default: returnValue = 50; break;
}
return returnValue; // Where is the clarity gained?
```

Comment: Some coding standards have a "no exceptions" rule. Those that also have a "single point of entry / single point of exit" rule justify the "no exceptions" rule on the basis of this singularly bad rule.

Answer (score 1):

Also, multiple exits could be some performance issue: when processor runs the current command, at the same clock tick it processes several next commands and performs some operations with them. So, if your code has multiple exits, like this:

```
if (condition)
  return a;
DoSomething();
if (condition2)
  return b;
```

and first condition is true, extraction of `DoSomething()` command will be useless.
Actually, with branch prediction it still can be fine, but anyway it is better keep this thing in mind.

Comment: No, its not performance issue in-fact low level programming do similar. It only programming style.

Comment: It does not matter what do you do: high level, or low level, your program can be sequential or contain cross-code jumps on both of them. Anyway jumps are not good for performance because of parallel instruction handling inside the processor. What is exactly the point you disagree with me?

Comment: Jump cause hard to bug a code that why structural programming come in concept. But execution efficiency is not a issue in high level programming(if its not a part of algorithm). So your answer is not related to question asked....any ways i was unaware of  that "jumps are not good for performance because of parallel instruction handling inside the processor". Good Point.

Comment: In a pure-functional approch, multi exit is the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your return value in a variable if you want to achieve this, but it's not true. You can have multiple returns in the same function without problems.