# How can I refactor code to remove if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I learnt everywhere that using if statement is a bad practice when it's possible to avoid them . I'm trying to learn how to make clean code, it seems also that some design patterns could be helpful so I'm wondering if it's possible to refactor this piece of code in order to remove if statement from, here is the code desmonstrating this:

```
public class Printer {

    private boolean on=false;
    private Job currentJob=null;
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void setOn(boolean _on){
        this.on=_on;
    }

    public boolean getOn(){
        return this.on;
    }

    public void setCurrentJob(Job _currentJob){
        this.currentJob=_currentJob;
    }

    public Job getCurrentJob(){
        return this.currentJob;
    }

    private boolean getOnStart(){
        setOn(true);
        return getOn();
    }

    public boolean start(){
        setOn(true);
        return on;
    }

    public boolean stop(){
        setOn(false);
        return !on;
    }

    public boolean suspend(){
        if (!isPrinting()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error");
        }
            currentJob.setState(Job.WAINTING);
            return true;
    }

    public boolean resume(){
        if (this.currentJob==null && currentJob.getState()!=0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error");
        }
            currentJob.setState(Job.PRINTING);
            return true;
    }

    public boolean cancel(){
        if (this.currentJob==null && currentJob.getState()!=0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error");
        }
            currentJob = null;
            return true;
    }
    public boolean print(Job aJob){
        if (isAvailable()){
            currentJob=aJob;
            aJob.setPrinter(this);
            aJob.setState(Job.PRINTING);
            return true;
        }
        System.err.println("Error");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean printingCompleted(){
        if (isPrinting()){
            currentJob.setPrinter(null);
            currentJob.setState(Job.COMPLETED);
            currentJob=null;
            return true;
        }
        System.err.println("Error");
        return false;
    }

    public void setSpooler(Spooler spool){
        spool.join(this);
    }

    public boolean isAvailable(){
        return on && currentJob==null;
    }

    public boolean isPrinting(){
        return on && currentJob!=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe `multiple exit points (read return)` in a method is bad. Having multiple ifs may not necessarily be bad if they are rightfully doing justice with the code.

Comment: *"using if statement is a bad practice"*--who told you this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `if` statements. I'd say keep them

Comment: Isn't this a question for codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: In this case I dont think there is a problem with `if` conditions. May be you can write method like this(I just feel that its better to have small `if`'s than `if` containing multiple lines)

`public boolean printingCompleted(){
    if(){
        System.err.println("Error");
        return false;
    }
        currentJob.setPrinter(null);
        currentJob.setState(Job.COMPLETED);
        currentJob=null;
        return true;
    
}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is much better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I just put the entire code, hope it could helps

Answer (score 2):

Using `if` incorrectly or excessively can sometimes indicate a code smell but I would not go so far as to say they should be avoided.

In your case they are indeed a little iffy. I would have coded your logic something like.

```
public void print(Job aJob) {
    if (!isAvailable()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot print when printer not available.");
    }
    currentJob = aJob;
    aJob.setPrinter(this);
    aJob.setState(Job.PRINTING);
}

public void printingCompleted() {
    if (!isPrinting()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Attempt to complete printing when no printing in progress.");
    }
    currentJob.setPrinter(null);
    currentJob.setState(Job.COMPLETED);
    currentJob = null;
}
```

This provides three benefits:

1. Errors can be handled/logged elsewhere.
2. You don't have to return `true` or `false` to indicate success/failure (a common smell).
3. Each method has a single exit point (a well known smell).

Answer (score 1):

> I learnt everywhere that using if statement is a bad practice when
>   it's possible to avoid them.

I actually agree with that. Perhaps I'm being too sensitive about the wording but if it's possible to avoid them, *to me*, means they weren't needed in the first place. Poorly written code can certainly contain unnecessary logic to do the same thing.

`if`s are an important aspect of the language. It would be silly to believe they should be avoided at all costs. Use them where needed that's what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there is nothing wrong with having `ifs` if they are rightfully needed. But you should avoid multiple exit points in your method. You can rewrite:

```
public boolean print(Job aJob){
    boolean result = false;
    if (isAvailable()){
        currentJob=aJob;
        aJob.setPrinter(this);
        aJob.setState(Job.PRINTING);
        result = true;
    }
    System.err.println("Error");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: *"you should avoid multiple exit points in your method"*--where do you all take this "wisdom" from? Additional `result` variable makes this less readable.

Comment: IMO, having multiple return statements in a single method should be avoided.

Comment: I have been told it is a good coding standard `Single Entry, Single Exit (SESE) `.

Comment: How can I avoid this ?

Comment: @Ryan: You do not need to avoid `ifs` as I mentioned if you need them.

Comment: @akhil_mittal in most Java SE implementation sources this idiom is broken, would you say they are badly coded?

Comment: Well I said we should avoid them if we can. I did not say they are badly coded :)

Comment: I think the important thing about SESE is to look at it in context and also think if it's a rule born from large amounts of hideous code. Code that even without MEs would stink like spoiled milk. On the other hand it has many good uses that make your code easier to read and write. A recursive algo that could be accomplished with 4 lines of code with MEs might require double, or more than, that with SEs if it's even reasonable. But even without recursion involved; does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745412/single-entry-single-exit-rule/12745899#12745899) look good to you?