# Need help making my switch case look nicer

Tags: c++, c++11

So basically my switch case works but my professor says there are too many returns and "use a variable result, then return it at the end!"

so here is my code

```
int getMonthValue(){
    switch(month){
        case(1): //January
            if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
                return 6;
            else
                return 0;
        case(2): // February
            if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
                return 2;
            else
                return 3;
        case(3): //March
            return 3;
        case(4): //April
            return 6;
        case(5): //May
            return 1;
        case(6): //June
            return 4;
        case(7): //July
            return 6;
        case(8): //August
            return 2;
        case(9): //September
            return 5;
        case(10): //October
            return 0;
        case(11): //November
            return 3;
        case(12): //December
            return 5;}
```

};

I dont see anything wrong with it, I am sure it could be written better. Would someone be able to show me a way to either format this in a more user friendly way? My professor also wanted me to use breaks in the switch instead, not sure why to use the break over return.

Comment: Why exactly are you returning those values for each month? What is the function doing exactly?

Comment: `int rval;`. set `rval` appropriately in the switch. `break` and finally `return rval;`

Comment: I like that user4581301, Ill work on that.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to calculate the day of week from a given date.  Could you use a global constant array and do an array lookup instead of switch-case?

Comment: and bi0phaz3 those values are what are provided as to each month for the calculations in the rest of the program.

Comment: I disagree with your professor. There are a lot of people who have this thing in their head that you should never have more than one return statement in the name of "good practice." Kinda dumb imo.

Comment: Another neat trick is a array of function pointers. The pointed-at function returns the appropriate number. use it like `return fparray[month]();`

Comment: There's a ton of different ways to do this, but what you have here is the cleanest overall idea. However, is `month` a global variable? If these numbers show up elsewhere you could do well to use constants.

Comment: No offense, but your professor seems to be obsessed with the so-called "single return rule", which in this case makes the code explicitly _worse_ than it is with multiple `return`s.  Storing the result, then returning it, would increase both the memory used (by 4 bytes, assuming 32-bit ints) and the number of ASM instructions required, while making the function slightly less readable (if you store the result instead of immediately returning it, it implies that you're going to use it before returning).

Comment: While there are indeed cases where it's a valid rule, just following an unofficial rule for the sake of following it is rarely a good idea.  Generally speaking, it's best to minimise the number of `return` statements, but still use more than one when it improves readability.  The rule can be useful in more complex cases, such as if you need to do cleanup for something RAII can't handle automatically, or if the value needs to be processed before being returned, but in simple cases where a value is just determined and immediately returned, it serves no benefit.

Comment: This is a fun case. You trade a large number of `return`s for a large number of `break`s. The `return`s result in less complexity, but more exit points. The `break` solution or the array-based solutions are harder to read. Ryan Haining and Justin Time have the right of it, to my thinking, but you still have to pass the class.

Comment: @user4581301 how is that less complex?

Comment: @RyanHaining complex is probably poor word choice on my part. I'm thinking mental complexity. What OP currently has with `return`s in place of `break`s is easier for the brain to handle. Or at least easier for my brain.

Comment: Anyone considered this could just be a simple test to see whether @Juscallmesteve can defend his solution or can tell why he thinks it is better (i.e. following arguments above)?

Comment: It's funny that with all the talk about this tiny style issue nobody mentioned the use of globals or the lack of bounds checking. A lot of the answers didn't add a bounds check. Obsessing over tiny style issues distracts from bigger style issues.

Comment: @Schwern I kinda assumed it was a member function of some class, and `month`, `year`, and `isLeapYear()` where other members.

Comment: @JustinTime Hmm. I'm not terribly familiar with C++ style, but wouldn't that require the function to have a namespace? `int DateSomething::getMonthValue() {...}`?

Comment: @Schwern If the function is defined outside the class definition, yes.  If it's defined inline, inside the class definition, though, it's already inside the class' scope, and thus doesn't need to be scoped.  If he defined the function inline, it's possible that the code was just copied from that.  This, for example, is valid: `class C { public: int func() { return 3; } };`

Answer (score 4):

This is not good idea to use logical operators in your case. Use a array! This code is very well understood and it is very fast. And it is very easy to change the return value:

```
unsigned getMonthValue(unsigned month, unsigned year) {
   const static unsigned ans[2][12] = {
//      Jan F  M  A  M  J  J  A  S  O  N  Dec
        {0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 }       //normal year 
      , {6, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5 }       //leap year
  };
  assert(month <= 12);
  assert(month >= 1);
  const size_t month_index = month - 1;
  const size_t leap = isLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 0;
  return ans[leap][month_index];
}
```

**UPDATE**

There is very useful link about this technic - [Lookup_table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table). Thanks to [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern)!

Comment: This is the best answer. It's very easy to read, very compact, and very fast. The general technique of using a data structure to lookup a value is known as a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
int getMonthValue(int month, int year){
map<int,int> staticAnswers;
staticAnswers[3] = 3;
staticAnswers[4] = 6;
staticAnswers[5] = 1;
staticAnswers[6] = 4;
staticAnswers[7] = 6;
staticAnswers[8] = 2;
staticAnswers[9] = 5;
staticAnswers[10] = 0;
staticAnswers[11] = 3;
staticAnswers[12] = 5;
switch(month){
    case(1): //January
        if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
            return 6;
        else
            return 0;
    case(2): // February
        if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
            return 2;
        else
            return 3;
    default:
        return staticAnswers[month];
};
```

Comment: Recommendation: Don't bother with the map. Just throw away 0, 1 and 2. What are a few bytes? If they do matter, subtract 3.

Comment: It looks like putting 1,2 also in `staticAnswer` could simpler your code further.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would write it:

```
int
getMonthValue (int month, int year)
{
    switch(month)
    {
    case 1: // January
         if (isLeapYear(year))
             return 6;  // explanation here of why 6 is the right value
         return 0;

    case 2: // February
         if (isLeapYear(year))
             return 2;  // explain why 2 is the right value
         return 3;

    case 3:   return 3;  // March
    case 4:   return 6;  // April
    case 5:   return 1;  // May
    case 6:   return 4;  // June
    case 7:   return 6;  // July
    case 8:   return 2;  // August
    case 9:   return 5;  // September
    case 10:  return 0;  // October
    case 11:  return 3;  // November
    case 12:  return 5;  // December
    }
}
```

I know many inexperienced programmers would object to the statements not being consistent.  However—written this way—the statement structure exactly follows the logic.  That is, the lexical structure reveals the logic.

Answer (score 0):

A good thing about `switch` statement is that you are allowed to *fall-through* `case` statements, so this is allowed in C++:

```
switch (month) {
  case 4:
  case 7:
    return 6;
  case 9:
  case 12:
    return 5;
```

Which should reduce the amount of `return` statements but will change the readable order.

Another option, since you are checking for all values in range `[1-12]`, would be to use an array, eg:

```
static const int values[] = { 3, 6, 1 ... };
if (month < 3) {
  /* leap year check */
}
else
  return values[month - 3]; // we subtract 3 to start from March
```

But this in the end should be mostly personal preference, so the suggestion given by the professor sounds like just something to nag you.

Comment: I had to downvote this. Using the fall-through feature of a case statement makes the code harder to read. Reorganizing it by return value also makes it harder to read, it's hard to find the value for a given month, it's harder to check all cases are covered.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is strictly enforcing the ["Single Entry, Single Exit"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12745412/14660) (SESE) rule of [Structured Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). All inputs come in as arguments. All output is via a single return statement at the end. No surprise returns in the middle of the routine. No globals. Minimal side effects. No gotos. It makes code easier to read when you don't have to carefully scan it for returns or calling gotos in the middle of a function.

This is a good rule of thumb. And at the time this was conceived, in the 1970s, this was a radical idea. Now it's just how you do things.

The problem, like many style rules, is when you strictly enforce the rule without considering *why* the rule exists; you can wind up with the opposite effect. [Some of the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814102/14660) have [illustrated that nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39813688/14660). Style rules are necessarily simplified versions of reality and enumerating all the edge cases and exceptions is difficult. Gotta allow some wiggle room.

For a small routine like yours that does one very clear thing, fits on one page, and is one easy to read switch statement... just do multiple returns like you're doing. Storing a return value for the end would make it longer and more complicated defeating the point of the rule. And you avoid forgetting a `break`, a very common C pitfall.

The other good reason to violate SESE is [early exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit). Structured programming says to do this:

```
int some_function(int arg) {
    int ret;

    if( arg < 0 ) {
        ret = arg;
    }
    else {
        this is the real
        meat and potatoes
        of the function
        and because of
        that one simple
        condition at the
        top it all
        is indented an
        extra level
        adding complexity
        to the whole
        function

        ret = whatever;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Every level of nesting adds complexity. Early exit avoids this unnecessary nesting by getting the simple cases out of the way at the top.

```
int some_function(int arg) {
    if( arg < 0 ) {
        return arg;
    }

    this is the real
    meat and potatoes
    of the function
    which doesn't
    have to be indented
    an extra level
    since we dealt with
    all the simple cases
    at the top

    return whatever;
}
```

The extra return at the start doesn't significantly add complexity because it's in a predictable spot. It's only surprise returns in the middle of a large function that are a problem.

---

The other side of this is minuscule style arguments like this can distract from real problems. Your code has two much bigger problems, and I hope your prof called you on them.

### Pass values into functions, don't use globals.

Your function takes no arguments. Instead `month` and `year` are globals. This is very bad style. It makes your program difficult to understand because anything can potentially effect anything. Instead, pass them in.

```
int getMonthValue( int month, int year ) {
    ...
}
```

### Check your bounds.

The second problem is your function has no bounds checking. What if `month` is 0? 13? -50? 20398? It will fall through the switch statement and out the bottom of the function. The compiler should have warned you about this.

```
test.c:48:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

To solve this, unless you can think of a good reason not to, always put a `default` clause on `switch`.

```
switch(month) {
    ...all your regular cases...

    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Month %d is out of range.\n", month);
        exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your professor is right, don't worry its all in the learning process

Try something like this:

```
    int result = -1;
    switch(month){
        case 1: //January
            if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
                result = 6;
            else
                result = 0;
        break;
        case 2: // February
            if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
                result = 2;
            else
                result = 3;
        break;
        case 3: //March
            result = 3;
        break;
        case 4: //April
            result = 6;
        break;
        case 5: //May
            result = 1;
        break;
        case 6: //June
            result = 4;
        break;
        case 7: //July
            result = 6;
        break;
        case 8 : //August
            result = 2;
        break;
        case 9: //September
            result = 5;
        break;
        case 10: //October
            result = 0;
        break;
        case 11: //November
            result = 3;
        break;
        case 12: //December
            result = 5;
        break;
    }
return result;
```

Also don't use brackets in your cases it doesnt look clean at all.

I sometimes also choose to use brackets in my cases "{" and "}" although in this example its probably more appropiate not to. Weather or not using brackets is the best practice I do not know.

I am refeering to these brackets by the way "{" and "}"

Anyway thats a cleaner case statement, hope it helped.

Answer (score -1):

a possible solution With the ternary operator!:

```
int getMonthValue()
{
    return 
        month == 3  ? 3 : 
        month == 4  ? 6 :
        month == 5  ? 1 :
        month == 6  ? 4 :
        month == 7  ? 6 :
        month == 8  ? 2 :
        month == 9  ? 5 :
        month == 10 ? 0 :
        month == 11 ? 3 :
        month == 12 ? 5 :
        month == 1  ?     isLeapYear(year) ? 6 : 0 :
        month == 2  && isLeapYear(year) ? 2 : 3 ;
}
```

Comment: I had to downvote this. It's far less efficient than a switch statement and a lot of extra work. It illustrates how the "one return at the end" dogma leads to ridiculous contortions.

Comment: @Schwern Have you tested its efficiency? in an optimzing compiler depends on condition all of `if..else` , `?:` and `switch.. case` converted to hash table so there is no difference in their efficiency! I think this is more readable than switch case

Comment: I'm having a hard time benchmarking it. The optimizer keeps optimizing away the calls. :) One thing I don't understand, why use `&&` in the last condition?

Comment: @Schwern try it replace `&&` with `?` , it cannot be compiled. Because  each `?` requires a corresponding `:` so in this case the number of `?` s becomes greater than the number of `:` s.

Comment: Ahh. I think this just adds to the reasons an enormous ternary is a bad idea. Sorry. :-/

Comment: @Schwern Thank you. If you are a downvoter you are not a mysterious downwoter :)